# Limit the length of input box to 16

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to limit the maxlength of input box to 16 characters but dash and space should not be included in count.
So far here is my code

JS

```
$('.numericSpaceDash').keypress(function(e){

    var xcode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    var maxlength = $('.cardtb').attr('maxlength', '16');

    var regex = new RegExp("[0-9\- ]");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);

    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
```

});

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="sf-cardno" class="tb cardtb rtb numericSpaceDash" autocomplete="off" name="cardno" maxlength="16"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you just have to remove spaces and dashes from the value, and check it's length

```js
$('.numericSpaceDash').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if ( [' ','-'].includes(e.key) ) {
          // do something if space or hyphen pressed
    } else if ( this.value.replace(/(\s|\-)/g,'').length > 15 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        $('#count').html( this.value.replace(/(\s|\-)/g,'').length +1 )
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="sf-cardno" class="tb cardtb rtb numericSpaceDash" name="cardno" />
<br />
Count : <span id="count"></span>
```

Note that jQuery normalizes `e.which`, you don't need to check for it.

Comment: I should be able to put up to 16 numbers when I use "-" or " " but what is happening here was I can only put up to 15 numbers. also when I didn't use "-" or "space" max length should be 16 but I can put 17 numbers with this code. Thanks though :)

Comment: @codeninja - I guess you'll need some additional conditions then. I've added some, see if that helps